# Cassandra - Cannot achieve consistency level QUORUM

Tags: cassandra

I'm running a single node at the moment. I'm trying to enable password authentication for Cassandra.

I'm following this guide: http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/operating/security.html#password-authentication

I'll note that I didn't alter `system_auth`'s replication as it's a single node cluster.

I edited `cassandra.yaml` to use `authenticator: PasswordAuthenticator`.

I then restarted cassandra and tried the command `cqlsh -u cassandra -p cassandra`, but that gives me the error:

```
Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers',
{'127.0.0.1': AuthenticationFailed(u'Failed to authenticate to 127.0.0.1: 
code=0100 [Bad credentials] message="org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.
UnavailableException: Cannot achieve consistency level QUORUM"',)})
```

I've tried running `nodetool repair` but it says: `Replication factor is 1. No repair is needed for keyspace 'system_auth'`

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem.

I had to run `ALTER KEYSPACE system_auth WITH replication = { 'class' : 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor' : 1 };` as it was set to `{'class': 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'DC1': '1', 'DC2': '1'}` previously, even though it was a single node cluster.

This is why it couldn't achieve a QUORUM.

Comment: how can you run ALTER KEYSPACE if you can't connect to cqlsh?

Comment: can you please help me with this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52404197/error-during-truncate-cannot-achieve-consistency-level-all-how-to-fix-i

Comment: Just change to `authenticator: AllowAllAuthenticator` in cassandra.yaml and login without credentials.

Answer (score 8):

Follow the below steps:

1. Set the **authenticator** in /etc/cassandra/cassandra.yaml file to **AllowAllAuthenticator**
2. Restart the cassandra
   **sudo service cassandra restart**
3. run the following commands
   cqlsh
   ALTER KEYSPACE system_auth WITH replication = { 'class' : 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor' : 1 };
4. Now change the authenticator again back to **PasswordAuthenticator**
5. Restart the cassandra
   **sudo service cassandra restart**
6. Now you will be able to login using the following command
   **cqlsh -u cassandra -p cassandra**

The issue is happening since a **system_auth** was set to {'class': 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'DC1': '1', 'DC2': '1'} previously, even though it was a single node cluster.

Answer (score 5):

http://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/4.8/datastax_enterprise/sec/secConfiguringInternalAuthentication.html

The user 'cassandra' always uses QUORUM in system_auth per default. Try creating a different user (as superuser) and your problem should be gone.

The reason is that you cannot have QUORUM on a single node cluser, see Igors Anwser.

Comment: As Igor also stated - you cannot achieve QUORUM on a single node cluster.

Comment: I get the error: `Unauthorized: code=2100 [Unauthorized] message="Only superusers can create a role with superuser status"` when I try creating a new user. Does this mean that I can't use password authentication on a single node cluster? am I better off just making it listen on localhost only in `cassandra.yaml` then to secure it?

Comment: If the cluster is under your control  - you can set AllowAllAuthenticator in cassandra.yaml and restart the node while creating your new superuser.

That error you got there is, you are trying to create a superuser as a normal user.

Comment: That's what it's set to at the moment, it still gives me that error when I try creating a new superuser. I also used that command after entering `cqlsh -u cassandra -p cassandra`. Isn't the cassandra role supposed to be a superuser?

Comment: The user cassandra is the default superuser - and that is always be checked as quorum in cassandra. 

If you are using AllowAllAuthenticator you can simply omit username and password. `cqlsh` alone should work.

Comment: I just ran into the same problem. For future readers, first remove password authentication, then alter the system_auth keyspace, then restore password authentication and *then* you can log back in as the cassandra role and do whatever else you wanted to do. You also *need* to be logged in as a superuser, and consequently, need to be using password auth in order to create other roles.

Answer (score 4):

In 1-node (or 2-node) configurations QUORUM is impossible, and repair is not needed (as it's used to fix data inconsistencies between nodes)

Answer (score 2):

In the `Cassandra.yaml` file, switch the authentication back to `authenticator: AllowAllAuthentication` and make sure `authorizer: AllowAllAuthorizer`
is set as well. This will allow you to use cqlsh again. It will no longer be checking for authentication before connecting. Once in cqlsh follow the other answers to lower the required replication to a lower level.

Answer (score 1):

In case you are using docker-desktop do the following:

- Use CLI of the docker image:
  [image]
- cd etc/cassandra
- vim cassandra.yml - to edit the file
- Change authenticator to **AllowAllAuthenticator**
- Restart the container and do following steps:
- docker-compose up -d image_name
- Refer below highlighted commands:

[image]

- Now swith back the authenticator to PasswordAuthenticator in cassandra.yaml
- Restart conatiner and now use below step to login to cqlsh:
  [image]

Answer (score 0):

What fixed it for me was go into the cqlsh shell, use the keyspace you're having issue's with, and run the command `CONSISTENCY QUORUM`